# Change cross-reference text in middle of the text to lowercase using showfieldcodes

Tags: vba, ms-word, paragraph

I want to change all the cross-reference text that are in middle of the text to lowercase, but not the ones at the beginning of a sentence.

The problem is that `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(row).Range.Text` is going through the original text, not the `ShowFieldCodes` (or Alt+F9 view), which generates longer paragraphs and rows.

```vb
Sub SetLowerCase()
Dim bBig As Boolean
Dim txt As String, row As String, pos As Integer
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^d REF"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        Do While .Execute
            pos = Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterColumnNumber)
            row = Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
            'The problem is that "ShowFieldCodes" generates longer paragraphs and more rows, which the next line does not take into account
            txt = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(row).Range.Text
            If pos = 1 Then
                bBig = True
            ElseIf Mid(txt, pos - 2, 2) = ". " Then
                bBig = True
            ElseIf Mid(txt, pos - 1, 1) = "." Then
                bBig = True
            End If
            If bBig = False Then
                If Not Selection.Text Like "*Lower*" Then
                    With Selection
                        .MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                        .MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                        .TypeText Text:="\*Lower "
                        .Fields.Update
                    End With
                End If
            Else
                bBig = False
            End If
            Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show an example or two of the kind of text you're trying to locate and change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Fld As Field, Rng As Range, StrRef As String
With ActiveDocument
  .ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
  For Each Fld In .Range.Fields
    With Fld
      If .Type = wdFieldRef Then
        Set Rng = .Result: StrRef = Split(Trim(.Code.Text), " ")(1)
        Rng.MoveStart wdSentence, -1
        Rng.MoveEnd wdSentence, 1
        If Rng.Sentences.Count = 1 Then
          .Code.Text = "REF " & StrRef & " \* Lower \h"
        Else
          .Code.Text = "REF " & StrRef & " \* FirstCap \h"
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
  .Fields.Update
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Whichever approach you take, you'll run up against VBA's ignorance of what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following:

*Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.*

For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5...

Comment: Hi Macropod, I tryed your solution and it turns all dieldref to lower and if two ref:s after eachother, then the 2:d ref gets broken, but i'll try to look in further into your code and see if I can use it.

Comment: I can see no possibility for the code to break any REF field - it doesn't in my testing, even when the are no spaces between two REF fields.  In my testing, REF fields at the start of a sentence get the first word capitalised. Regardless, I've edited the code to make it more reliable - but see the caveat in my answer about VBA & sentences.

Comment: My bad, my previous attempts added some extra spaces in the ref, that broke the ref. Your code works fine, but it doesn't set a big letter at beginning of a new row. Is that possible to handle?

Comment: Code revised. Try it now,

Comment: Marvallous, thank you so much!! I helped like 5 others with there problems, while waiting for help here :)